# WAS 7.0 to Liberty Migration

Tags: spring, websphere, jndi, websphere-liberty

I am migrating my app from WAS 7.0 to Liberty 8.5.5. I am stuck in JNDI configuration, there is different configuration setting in WAS 7 with spring but having doubt how can configure same setting in Liberty to get JNDI + Spring + Liberty get work. there are some library which are also not supported by Liberty which was supported in WAS 7.
I am getting the below error-:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:91)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASInitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(WASInitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:55)
    at [internal classes]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:695)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:324)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:255)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.createInitialContext(JndiTemplate.java:136)
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can delete references to com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory since it's not present in Liberty.  Some other default context factory will be used instead if one isn't explicitly specified.   An example of using jndi in Liberty can be found here: 

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jndi.html

Comment: The error suggests that the `WsnInitialContextFactory` class *is* being found, but it is failing to be initialized for some reason.  There should be a "Caused by" after the stack trace, or there should be another stack trace in the logs that includes `WsnInitialContextFactory.<clinit>`.  That said, are you packaging a thinclient JAR in your application?  There is probably a better solution...

Comment: @BrettKail thank you, its somehow referring to WAS7 jar i removed that jar and its works ! Thanks you again.